# Python 3.5.0 ::: Apagar uma Label no Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label

Eu tenho um código que me permite jogar ao pedra-papel-tesoura. Eis a janela tkinter:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não aparece o resultado de cada vez que jogo, porque a label desse texto não desaparece nem apaga o texto. Como é que eu faço para conseguir ver o resultado todas as vezes que jogo.

Eis o código:

```
#JOGO PEDRA-PAPEL-TESOURA
#TKINTER MODULE

from tkinter import *
import random
ppt = ['pedra', 'papel', 'tesoura']
res = 'JOGAR'

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.title('ROCK - PAPER - SCISSORS')

frame_texto = Frame(root)
frame_texto.pack(side=BOTTOM)
frame_texto.place(height=100, width=200, x=300, y=300)

def res_texto(res):
    texto = Label(frame_texto, text= res, fg='red', font=('Times New Roman', 40))
    texto.pack()

def jogar_pedra(event):
    x = random.choice(ppt)
    if x == 'pedra':
        res = 'EMPATE'
        res_texto(res)
    elif x == 'papel':
        res = 'PERDEU'
        res_texto(res)
    elif x == 'tesoura':
        res = 'GANHOU'
        res_texto(res)

def jogar_papel(event):
    x = random.choice(ppt)
    if x == 'pedra':
        res = 'GANHOU'
        res_texto(res)
    elif x == 'papel':
        res = 'EMPATE'
        res_texto(res)
    elif x == 'tesoura':
        res = 'PERDEU'
        res_texto(res)

def jogar_tesoura(event):
    x = random.choice(ppt)
    if x == 'pedra':
        res = 'PERDEU'
        res_texto(res)
    elif x == 'papel':
        res = 'GANHOU'
        res_texto(res)
    elif x == 'tesoura':
        res = 'EMPATE'
        res_texto(res)



instrucoes = Label(root, text='Escolha pedra, papel ou tesoura', font = ('Times New Roman', 20), fg='black')
instrucoes.pack()

pedra = Button(root, text='Pedra', font=(30))
pedra.bind('<Button-1>', jogar_pedra)
pedra.pack()
pedra.place(x=250, y=100)

papel = Button(root, text='Papel', font=(30))
papel.bind('<Button-1>', jogar_papel)
papel.pack()
papel.place(x= 350, y=100)

tesoura = Button(root, text='Tesoura', font=(30))
tesoura.bind('<Button-1>', jogar_tesoura)
tesoura.pack()
tesoura.place(x=450, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes passar ao teu problema concreto, queria dizer que `place` não é muito usado ou é sobretudo usado em específicos casos. Eu por exemplo quase nunca usei `place`, e normalmente uso uma combinação de `grid` e `pack`, e acredita que uma vez que percebes como esses aí funcionam, raramente precisarás de `place`. Conclusão, saber usar `grid` e `pack` bem ajuda-te quase em todas as situações onde tens que criar diversos layouts.

Tirando este conselho, o teu problema é que quando chamas a função `res_texto` to continuas a criar uma `Label` e a "packa-la". O conselho é que tu cries essa `Label` uma vez e sucessivamente modificas só o texto dela.

```
#JOGO PEDRA-PAPEL-TESOURA
#TKINTER MODULE

from tkinter import *
import random


ppt = ['pedra', 'papel', 'tesoura']
res = 'JOGAR'

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.title('ROCK - PAPER - SCISSORS')

frame_texto = Frame(root)
frame_texto.pack(side=BOTTOM)
frame_texto.place(height=100, width=200, x=300, y=300)

# Creias 1 vez a label
texto = Label(frame_texto, text= res, fg='red', font=('Times New Roman', 40))
texto.pack()

# Aqui só modificas o texto da Label texto
def res_texto(res):
    texto.config(text=res)

def jogar_pedra(event):
    x = random.choice(ppt)
    if x == 'pedra':
        res = 'EMPATE'
        res_texto(res)
    elif x == 'papel':
        res = 'PERDEU'
        res_texto(res)
    elif x == 'tesoura':
        res = 'GANHOU'
        res_texto(res)

def jogar_papel(event):
    x = random.choice(ppt)
    if x == 'pedra':
        res = 'GANHOU'
        res_texto(res)
    elif x == 'papel':
        res = 'EMPATE'
        res_texto(res)
    elif x == 'tesoura':
        res = 'PERDEU'
        res_texto(res)

def jogar_tesoura(event):
    x = random.choice(ppt)
    if x == 'pedra':
        res = 'PERDEU'
        res_texto(res)
    elif x == 'papel':
        res = 'GANHOU'
        res_texto(res)
    elif x == 'tesoura':
        res = 'EMPATE'
        res_texto(res)


instrucoes = Label(root, text='Escolha pedra, papel ou tesoura', font = ('Times New Roman', 20), fg='black')
instrucoes.pack()

pedra = Button(root, text='Pedra', font=(30))
pedra.bind('<Button-1>', jogar_pedra)
pedra.pack()
pedra.place(x=250, y=100)

papel = Button(root, text='Papel', font=(30))
papel.bind('<Button-1>', jogar_papel)
papel.pack()
papel.place(x= 350, y=100)

tesoura = Button(root, text='Tesoura', font=(30))
tesoura.bind('<Button-1>', jogar_tesoura)
tesoura.pack()
tesoura.place(x=450, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara tem uma forma de "deletar " usando .place SIM
basta que voce apos uma açao adicionar uma posiçao que nao seja visivel em sua janela, por exemplo:

```
jan = Tk()
jan.geometry("500x400")

nome = Label(jan, text="Ganhou")
nome.place(x=200,  y=200)
```

> def ok():
>
> ```
>  nome.place(x=600, y=500)
> ```

```
bt = Button(jan, text="OK", command=ok)
bt.place(x=200, y=250)
```

> Perceba que coloquei uma posição que nao existe em minha janela
>   e  para n perceber de forma alguma mesmo quando abrir a janela adicione 
>   uma posiçao absurda ex: (x=2000, y=4000)